# Excluding URLs from Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Search

Tags: 2013, search-results

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2013.  I am having an issue excluding URLs from my search results.

We have setup the search query to only search a particular subsite which is a List that has several thousand individual items.  We also have Views created on that list.  The problem we are having is the views come back listed in the search results.  I want just the list items to return and do not want the view URLs.

This is what I am using for my default content source query.

```
{searchTerms} path:http://sharepointsite/productenhancementlist
```

I have tried creating crawl rules to exclude the specific view urls and reset the index and did a full crawl and then I got back no results for our List.

If I remove the crawl rules and then remove the urls from the search results with the built in functionality they come back the next time an incremental crawl runs which we have set to run ever 2 hours.

So my question is, how can I have these urls permanently removed from search results?

Example:

```
    Search results only brings back results from 
    http://sharepointsite/productenhancementlist/ this includes
    http://sharepointsite/productenhancementlist/view1.aspx view2.aspx etc...
    as well as the results we want 
    http://sharepointsite/productenhancementlist/DispForm.aspx?ID=1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this query:
 `path:"http://melcher.it/projects" (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")`